# JFrame behaving weirdly

Tags: java, swing, components, jframe, jinternalframe

In my program, I am displaying images with a song in background.
After song is finished, i need to close frame and `JInternalFrame`.
Here is the code:

```
package projectfinal;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/* MORE IMPORTS */
public class ImagePanel extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static class audio extends JApplet {

        private static final int EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 128000;

        public void aaudio() {

            String strFilename = "E:/zehreelay.wav";
            File soundFile = new File(strFilename);


            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
            try {
                audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }


            AudioFormat audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();

            SourceDataLine line = null;
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class,
                audioFormat);
            try {
                line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

                line.open(audioFormat);
            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
            line.start();
            int nBytesRead = 0;
            byte[] abData = new byte[EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE];
            while (nBytesRead != -1) {
                try {
                    nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
                    int nBytesWritten = line.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
                }

            }
            line.drain();

            line.close();

            jInternalFrame1.setVisible(false);
            /**
            * closing internal frame
            */
        }
    }

    /**
    * Creates new form NewJFrame
    */
    public ImagePanel() {

        initComponents();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());

        //////////more code////////////////////////////////////
        jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
        jInternalFrame1.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {

            public void componentHidden(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
                hiden(evt);
            }
        });
        /////adding a listner for component///
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        start();

    }

    private void hiden(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {

        setVisible(false);
    }

    public static void start() {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new ImagePanel().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        audio obj = new audio();
        obj.aaudio();
    }
    private static javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
/////more variables...//////
}
```

This code is fine, but when I tried out *without* adding a component listener,
that is, `getRootPane().SetVisible(false)` or `jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setVisible(false)` or `setVisible(false)` none of them was working, but it worked out only after adding a component hidden listener. Why? Any reasons?Then how come `JInternalFrame` was working (`JInternalFrame.setVisible(false)`)? Is this something to do with `rootPane()`?

Comment: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @trashgod then why does it work fine if we just normally say setVisible(false) ?Why not in this case?

Comment: Trashgod is right. Why can't you wrap the call in the SwingUtilities.invokeLater?

Comment: @StanislavL I dont want to use AWT dispatch thread.

Comment: I've cited two approaches [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13902199/230513).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), "An initial thread schedules the GUI creation task by invoking `invokeLater` or `invokeAndWait`." You are trying to both play a sound and operate a GUI on the same initial thread. Instead, start the sound on the initial thread and construct the GUI on the EDT, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10670509/230513), or start a separate thread to play the sound, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12548978/230513).

> I don't want to use AWT dispatch thread.

Right, you don't want to use the AWT event dispatch thread to play sound, but you *must* use it for the GUI.

> The question is somewhat unanswered. The playing of sound is light, so must be handled by single EDT.

I can only speculate that using a different component changed the timing enough to affect the result on your platform. Until the program is correctly synchronized, there's always some environment in which it will work and some in which it will fail. The essential rule is this: don't block the EDT. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7809480/230513), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26318/230513) and the [Java Sound](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) tag.

Comment: thanks.But,the question is somewhat unanswred.The playing of sound is Light,so must be handled by single EDT