# Guice and Swing's concurrency model are seemingly incompatible

Tags: swing, concurrency, guice

Guice 4.0 here. I've been using Guice for a few years now and really love it. I now have a need for a Swing app and am baffled at how to contrive the Guice API to meet Swing's (IMHO) bizarre requirements/best practices.

Typically, when I use Guice, I have a main "driver" class like `MyApp` which I wire with Guice like so:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
class MyApp {
    @Inject
    FizzClient fizzClient

    @Inject
    BuzzClien buzzClient

    static void main(String[] args) {
        MyApp myapp = Guice.createInjector(new MyAppModule()).getInstance(MyApp)
        myapp.run()
    }

    private void run() {
        // Do whatever the app does...
    }
}

class MyAppModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    void configure() {
        bind(FizzClient).to(DefaultFizzClient)
        bind(BuzzClient).to(DefaultBuzzClient)
        // etc...
    }
}
```

But in the case of Swing, the `JFrame` *is* the GUI application, and so to me, it makes sense to have `MyApp` extend `JFrame`:

```
class MyApp extends JFrame {
    // etc...
}
```

The problem is that, in Swing, you need to do some unconventional thread trickery so that:

1. Any code that manipulates the `JFrame` or the other `JComponents` of the UI needs to happen on the Event Dispatching Thread (**EDT**) - this is accomplished via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`; and
2. Any code that will block and take a while to finish needs to be siphoned off into its own `SwingWorker` thread

So let's say I have a need to warm up a large cache at app startup (perhaps this takes 30 - 60 seconds). Here's my best attempt thus far:

```
@Canonical // Creates a tuple constructor and a bunch of other stuff for me
@Slf4j
class MyApp extends JFrame {
    @Inject
    MyAppCache appCache

    static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            void run() {
                // The Guice-based bootstrapping has to happen inside invokeLater
                // because MyApp *is* a JFrame (hence UI).
                Guice.createInjector(new MyAppModule()).getInsance(MyApp).init()
            }  
        })
    }

    void init() {
        new SwingWorker<Void,String>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() {
                appCache.warmUp()
                publish('Cached is warmed up!')
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> updates) {
                log.info(updates)
            }
        }.execute()
    }
}

class MyAppModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    void configure() {
        bind(MyAppCache).to(DefaultAppCache)
    }

    @Provides
    MyApp providesMyApp(MyAppCache appCache) {
        MyApp app = new MyApp(appCache)
        app.title = 'My App'
        app.defaultCloseOperation = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
        app.pack()
        // ...etc. (configure the parent JFrame)
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get a NPE on the `appCache.warmUp()` statement inside the `SwingWorker`. This is because the above code actually involves 3 threads:

- **main** - where `main` & `init` are running
- **EDT** - where Guice is bootstrapping the `MyApp` instance
- **Swing Worker** - where the `SwingWorker` is running and attempting to warmup the cache

And so by the time we go to execute the Swing worker, Guice hasn't had a chance to bootstrap the `MyApp` instance yet (and thus, its cache property).

Ay ideas at all (w/ specific code example) how I can get Guice working properly with Swing's concurrency model?

Comment: You're invoking `init` yourself in the Runnable passed to `invokeLater`. Why would it be run on the main thread and not the EDT thread?

Comment: I would be genuinely interested to learn of a GUI library that is _not_ single threaded.

Comment: Thanks @JeffBowman (+1) - because `SwingWorker` does some magic - run this code yourself, you'll see the worker code executes inside its own thread, separate from main and the EDT.

Comment: I am interested to see the full stacktrace. As you are executing injector.getInstance(MyApp.class).init(), the MyApp is ready, so totally injected. You have a typo in your code ("getInsance") : I assume the code I see here is not the code you execute, and the bug is probably not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with [guice](/questions/tagged/guice), but you can continue any non-GUI initialization after invoking `EventQueue.invokeLater()`—such code will simply run on the [initial thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). An example may be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10670509/230513). Of course, you must synchronize access to any shared data, but you can update the GUI when the initial thread concludes using `EventQueue.invokeLater()` in the usual way. Your GUI should forestall use of any incomplete data in the interim.

As an aside, I see no reason for `MyApp` to extend `JFrame`. Instead, `add()` your enclosing `Container` to an instance of `JFrame`. Several examples are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513).

Comment: Thanks @trashgod (+1) - but *believe* me, I've tried everything, even making `MyApp` *not* extend `JFrame`. **However, an answer to the following question might give me a solution here:** So Guice bootstrapping must happen on one of the threads: main, EDT or the Swing Worker ("*Cache Warmer*") thread. Honestly, I don't care which one it is. However, I *need* Guice to have bootstrapped and wired up the `MyApp` instance *before* the Cache Warmer Thread attempts to warm up the cache.

Comment: So perhaps all I need to do is to do some synchronization to make sure that the Cache Warmer thread waits for Guice injection to complete. Any ideas how I might accomplish this (even with no Guice experience, all the code is provided above)?

Comment: Not sure I can offer a panacea; as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513), you can use `CountDownLatch` to synchronize non-GUI threads; also beware of [busy loops](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35154352/230513).